# Вопрос по MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Подскажите такую вещь, есть таблица record c полями id_record, id_export, id_import, также есть таблица score с полями id_score, score. Поля id_export и id_import из первой таблицы связаны с id_score из второй. Нужно в первой таблице вместо id'шников вывести соответствующие имена из второй.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Джойны же

```
SELECT t1.id_record, j1.score, j2.score
FROM table1 AS t1
OUTER JOIN table2 AS j1 ON t1.id_export = j1.id_score
OUTER JOIN table2 AS j2 ON t1.id_import = j2.id_score
```

Наверняка где-то налажал, но решается точно через джойны.